# understanding linux help flags (awk command)

Tags: linux

I'm linux learner. I have learned "awk" there when i type awk in terminal it shows

```
usage: awk [-F fs] [-v var=value] [-f progfile | 'prog'] [file ...]
```

I want to understand what is `-F` `fs` and `-v` `var=value`. I have no idea to undertand what it hints. Please help me.

Comment: Does this post help?  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193815/99989

Comment: read the man page of `awk`

Comment: Good awk tutorial at http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck.

Comment: As vinod says, type `man awk`.  The man pages are are good source of information for most of the commands.  They are primarily intended not as tutorials, but as reference material, so they may sometimes not be particularly helpful to a newbie.